# Mapping country code to country name php

Tags: php, json

I have a function that I found on here to get the user ip to country. but it only shows the abrev I want to show the full country as well as the abrev

```
function ip_details($IPaddress)
{
    $json       = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$IPaddress}");
    $details    = json_decode($json);
    return $details;
}

$IPaddress  =  'get ip here';

$details    =   ip_details("$IPaddress");

echo $details->region;
echo $details->country;
```

then I echo where I want it like this.

```
<?php echo $details->country;?>
```

So I went to [IpInfo Site](https://ipinfo.io/developers/full-country-names)

it tells me to download and map I have downloaded the json file but unsure how to map it so that I can echo out the full country name when needed

Comment: can you share `print_r($details)`?

Comment: the link is at the top plus I show you how I echo out the info

Comment: Country field only contains abbrevation. It does not contain complete name.

Comment: please share the result using var_dump or the error code

Comment: Do you want to show country name abbreviation and complete name? Is this the only thing you want?

Comment: I have it set up and it shows country code city and state which is all the info I need what I am trying to do is also show full country name so I want to show 4 things country abrev country full name city and state

Comment: @Codi see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet gets the output I think you want from the JSON.

You can substitute the hard-coded IP address for the the value from your script once you're happy with this.

```
$countries = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://country.io/names.json'));
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8"));
$code = $details->country;
echo "Country Name: ".$countries->$code."<br/>";
echo "Country Code: ".$code."<br/>";
echo "Region: ".$details->region."<br/>";
echo "City: ".$details->city."<br/>";
```

This outputs:

```
Country Name: United States
Country Code: US
Region: California
City: Mountain View
```

Comment: @Codi Try this one. This is what you are looking for.

Comment: perfect just what I was needing

Comment: @Codi no problem, happy to help

Comment: I was trying to play slick because I have the flag images but they were all lower case abrev so I can echo code on image link to show it lol

Comment: @Codi you could always convert them to upper-case in order to match them to these ones

Answer (score 2):

I would take the country codes from the JSON and create a PHP array in your code for quick lookup.

```
$countryCodes = ['BD'=>'Bangladesh', ...];

if ( array_key_exists($details->country, $countryCodes) {
  $country = $countryCodes[$details->country];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below function to get the country name from country code:

```
function getCountryName($code) {
    $json = file_get_contents("http://country.io/names.json");
    $countries = json_decode($json, TRUE);

    return array_key_exists($code,$countries) ? $countries[$code] : false;
}
```

As a improvement, you can download the `http://country.io/names.json` json file and refer it here instead of calling it remotely every time.

Comment: "As a improvement, you can download the http://country.io/names.json json file and refer it here instead of calling it remotely every time." That's not an improvement if the file ever gets changed by the people who maintain it. Which it might, when countries change their name, cease to exist, get created etc, which sometimes happens

Comment: @PSJ I downloaded it what I need is the following country full name country code US region and city I tried echoing the above out but its blank

Answer (score -2):

You will need to use PHP's `json_decode` function to turn the JSON data into an array.

Example:

```
$country_json = file_get_contents('http://country.io/names.json');
$country_array = json_decode($country_json, TRUE); // TRUE turns the result into an associative array

echo $country_array[$details->country];
```

Comment: "You will need to use PHP's json_decode function". OP's code already does. Your version just converts it to an array and instead of an object, which is probably less useful than the object. I doubt that is the root of the issue.

Comment: OP's code is getting details about the user IP. He wants to map it to a JSON list of countries. Since his question was about how to make the JSON data usable I thought I would include `json_decode` just in case his code sample came from somewhere else and he doesn't fully understand it.

Comment: ok but it's worded like they didn't use the function at all. And I'd still say that an object-style output is neater, but that's an opinion only.

Comment: After re-reading the question the OP says he found the function and doesn't know how to parse JSON so I still feel like instructing him to use `json_decode` even though he already is in his snippet is correct. But I understand what you're saying.